# Setting window title with Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, .net, caliburn.micro

I have a view model that inherits the `Screen` class and a window which is a view for this model. `Screen` class has a property `DisplayName` and Caliburn.Micro binds the window title to this property but I want it to be bound to a dynamic resource which I add to the window in `WindowManager.EnsureWindow` override.

Is there any way to prevent Caliburn.Micro from automatically binding window title to the `DisplayName` property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create the binding manually on the window like this:

```
Title={DynamicResource .... }
```

Caliburn.Micro will respect your choice.

Comment: I have that already, hmm.. but it is in a separate style which Caliburn.Micro is not aware of at the moment of view initialization. I now know what I need to do, thanks!

Comment: @0wl You are welcome, glad I could help, although I didn't feel very helpful this time :).